# Pandas Python problema with match value excel

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, match

i have an excel with this values in te column A:

```
  A
```

first column

0 3971118279

0 397111859

2 397111859

2 790ZR64-60-0

3 790ZR64-60-0

4 V4B7506333

5 V4B7506333

I read with pandas and merge with openpyxl the especific cell:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(Cfijopath, index_col=None )
wb = load_workbook(Cfijopath)
ws = wb.active

for r in df1.index:
    il = df1.iloc[r,0]
    il = str(il)
    if il == 'nan':
        print('NAN')
    else:
        try:
            index = df1.index[df1['first column'] == il].tolist()
            fir = index[0]
            sec = index[-1]
            ws.merge_cells(f'A{fir}:A{sec}')
        except:
            print('error')
wb.save(Cfijopath)
```

The code work, but when compare the first value (3971118279) doesnt match.
i tried with:

```
index = df1.index[df1['first column'] == '3971118279'].tolist()
```

and not work.

This happens with values that have only numbers, how i can compare to get the index in this cases?

### Thanks.

**Update.
Finally tested only with openpyxl and happened the same.
In the code of below has the "solution":**

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
ws = wb.active
for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            val = str(cell.value)
            if val == "3971118279":
                print(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).row)
                print(type(cell.value))
                print(type(val))
```

Output:

```
2
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
3
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```

The problem happen because the cell value with only numbers is considered "int".
The solution is convert to "str" before the compare.

Comment: so u mean when you compare it with 'V4B7506333' it works, but with 397111859, it fails? Also, why cant you run the entire process in Pandas or openpyxl, why the combination?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using index_col == None if you're not using indexes. Generally if you want to iterate over the elements in a specific row you should try using instead:
for idx, item in df1['first column'].iteritems():
    # do thing
Secondly, if you watch to check if an item is null or not I would suggest using pd.isna(df1,iloc[0]['first column']), that will return either False or True. Also, for matching string values you could try using df1['first column'].str.contains('string you are checking', case=False).

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @sammywemmy yes. I use Pandas to pivot in other function and openpyxl to merge specific cell condition, i will try with only openpyxl in this function.

Comment: @Alex The part of the il = nan  is a part of old code, i forgot erase it. The real data have more columns, i use the match for get the index number and merge this rows whit specific values. With str.contains i can get the index?
Thanks.

Comment: @AMC I will post.

Comment: @AlenOrellana I'm not sure I understand where the example output you shared fits into the issue.

Comment: @AMC that output is for the code of "update" where use only openpyxl.

Answer (score 0):

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
ws = wb.active
for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            val = str(cell.value)
            if val == "3971118279":
                print(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).row)
                print(type(cell.value))
                print(type(val))

Output:

2
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
3
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```

The problem happen because the cell value with only numbers is considered "int". The solution is convert to "str" before the compare